# Moodle course completion status not updating in mobile app

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I am created new course and some topics in course , set course tracking settings via Admin side . Added permission to the user's to manually closed the status (read/view status) for lessons (Course lessons).
In web application the status shows lessons are completed by user (Tick Mark)
[image]

so in Web applications admin side it shows activities completed.

But i access the course information in mobile App it shows basics of PHP and PHP5 syntax sections are not started

[image]

I am stuck with this section . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it finally:Issue because of cron setting , actually status updated successfully , but mobile status updates only after cron running